# Can't get Windows Server 2008 to move past the first restart during installation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid, installation, intel

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2008 Small Business Edition using the following hardware:

- Intel S3420GP Motherboard
- 3400 socket XEON CPU
- Samsung DVD Drive
- 2x 250 GB Hard Drives in RAID 1

I booted to the DVD and went through the Windows installation product, entering my product key, choosing a partition, and all that stuff.  Everything seemed to go smoothly until the first reboot.

When I rebooted the first time, it came back to the exact same installation screen as if the first installation attempt didn't even happen.  I checked the files on the hard drive, and I can see several GB of standard Windows folders, indicating that *something* was copied over during the first installation attempt.

If I remove the Windows DVD from the drive and reboot, I'm brought to a screen that simply says:

```
NO BOOTABLE PARTITION FOUND IN TABLE
```

What might I try to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you add information on what is defining the RAID? 3rd party card or BIOS based SATA RAID?

Comment: it was SATA RAID running off of the embedded RAID controller on the Intel motherboard.  I made some adjustments there at that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first reboot, you need to make sure that your BIOS doesn't default to booting from the disk drive, largely because it needs to boot from the hard disk. However, the disk does need to stay in the drive, because to finish the installation you need to have the disk.

Comment: I think you mean BIOS does not default to booting from the CD/DVD drive, because it needs to boot from the hard disk....

Comment: you know, I think it was a mix of the RAID setup and my flash drive causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Advised bmccormack to check the RAID information (17th Jan 2010) to see if that resolved the issue. Adding this here so that bmccormack can mark this as correct and update with the relevant information.